# How does tire pressure affect susceptility to hydroplane?

Tags: tires, pressure

Is a tire's propensity to hydroplane proportional or inversely proportional to tire pressure?  That is, if a tire is over inflated or under inflated, is it more or less likely to hydroplane?
**Edit:** This subject came up in [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24374/checking-tire-pressure-when-the-tire-is-warm-or-cold/24376?noredirect=1#comment37331_24376) thread and the moderators agreed that it deserved its own question. That's why it's posted here.

Comment: This comes up in Airline Transport Pilot Licence exams. The correct answer is that the Hydroplaning speed increases with higher tyre pressure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [this](http://www.nhtsa.gov/cars/rules/rulings/TPMS_FMVSS_No138/part5.6.html) article by the NHTSA a formula is given for calculating the speed at which a tire might be expected to hydroplane. The formula assumes "...the water depth exceeds the capability of the tread design to remove water." The formula is:

> Hydroplaning speed = 10.35 x √ inflation pressure

As some examples they give this table:

> - At 30 psi, hydroplaning could occur at 56.7 mph
> - at 25 psi, hydroplaning could occur at 51.8 mph
> - At 20 psi, hydroplaning could occur at 46.3 mph.

Clearly, the lower the tire pressure the more likely a tire is to hydroplane.
There are two main reasons for this

- A tire with lower inflation pressure has more contact area, and it, therefore, takes less pressure to lift the tire off the pavement.
- A tire with lower inflation pressure presents a slightly concave profile to the pavement. This causes water trapped under the tire to be directed towards the tire's center line rather than away from it.

[Source](http://www.tirerack.com/winter/tech/techpage.jsp?techid=3)
Conversely, a tire with higher pressure presents less contact area, which therefore requires more pressure to lift the tire off of the pavement, and it presents a slightly convex profile to the pavement, which directs water towards the outside of the tire rather than towards its center.

Answer (score 0):

This discounts tread type and tread depth.  Tire rubber hardness is also in play.  A rain tire and a slick will perform very differently in similar wet conditions.  Best advice would be to always slow down in wet conditions.